# How do I drag a JOIN formula in Google Sheets and ignore the rows that have been joined in the above cell?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to create a tool in Google Sheets that allows someone to paste a large number of serial numbers into a column and it will automatically JOIN the serial numbers by groups of 80 and split them by ",".

The formula I have for the first cell is:

```
=JOIN(",",A1:A80)
```

This works fine, but I need to drag this formula down to facilitate 1000s of serial numbers. The problem I'm facing is that when I drag the formula down, it applies to `A2:A81`, then `A3:A82` and so on. But what I need is `A81:A160`, then `A161:A240` etc.

Does anyone know of an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to use:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",1,QUERY(A:A,"limit 80 offset "&(ROW(A1)-1)*80))
```

Using `TEXTJOIN()` instead of `JOIN()` to avoid trailing commas when values run out at the end of `A:A`. See the example below with concatenating 3 consecutive values:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

a litle bit of math...

```
="A"&80*(ROW(A1)-1)+1&":A"&80*ROW(A1)
```

[image]

so try:

```
=JOIN(",", INDIRECT("A"&80*(ROW(A1)-1)+1&":A"&80*ROW(A1)))
```